# My directive isn't being detected by Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong, but I'm practicing custom directives and don't understand why my directive isn't working.

Here's the markup:

```
<div ng-app="main">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{ message }}
    <actionBar></actionBar>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('main', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello.";
    $scope.doStuff = function (cb) {
      alert('Doing stuff...');
      cb();
    };
  })
  .directive('actionBar', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      template: '<h1>test</h1>',
      scope: {
        doStuff: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        alert('test');
        scope.doStuff(function () {
          alert('callback executed');
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Here's a codepen:

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/hteBE/

The `{{ message }}` placeholder is correctly replaced with "Hello." but the `<actionBar>` tag just ends up in the browser and the directive's link function never runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the HTML you need to reference the directive with:

```
<action-bar> ... </action-bar>
```

instead of

```
<actionBar> ... </actionBar>
```

Comment: I also discovered that all directive tags **must** have an opening and closing tag. No self-closing tags allowed.